# Is there a help() for pandas that is similar to python help('builtins')

Tags: python, pandas

Just wondering if there is any help() similar to that of python help() in case of pandas, matplotlib, seaborn etc.

As it is very easy and handy to use help() on any python interpreters, kindly point me for any such ways we can do with advanced topics of python like pandas other than online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to use dir()

```
import pandas as pd
print(dir(pd))
print(dir(pd.DataFrame))
```